# exit status of command is different when it is run via strace

Tags: mount, ftp, fuse, strace, exit-status

I can normaly mount/umount FTP as file system using following commands:

```
└──> curlftpfs -o codepage=windows-1250 anonymous:anonymous@192.168.3.13 /home/marek/ftpfs
└──> ls /home/marek/ftpfs/
1 2 3
└──> fusermount -u /home/marek/ftpfs
└──> ls /home/marek/ftpfs/
└──>
```

But when I issue `curlftpfs` with `strace` then nothing is mounted and the process exits with status 1:

```
└──> strace -f curlftpfs -o codepage=windows-1250 anonymous:anonymous@192.168.3.13 /home/marek/ftpfs
└──> echo $0
1
└──> ls /home/marek/ftpfs/
└──>
```

Last lines from `strace` (full output is [here](http://pastebin.com/btN5vKvz)):

```
[pid  9619] mprotect(0x7f08780b2000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
[pid  9619] mprotect(0x7f08782bd000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
[pid  9619] munmap(0x7f0878e8d000, 135950) = 0
[pid  9619] open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
[pid  9619] lseek(6, 0, SEEK_CUR)       = 0
[pid  9619] fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2290, ...}) = 0
[pid  9619] mmap(NULL, 2290, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 6, 0) = 0x7f0878eae000
[pid  9619] lseek(6, 2290, SEEK_SET)    = 2290
[pid  9619] munmap(0x7f0878eae000, 2290) = 0
[pid  9619] close(6)                    = 0
[pid  9619] getgid()                    = 1000
[pid  9619] getuid()                    = 1000
[pid  9619] openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
[pid  9619] getdents(6, /* 2 entries */, 32768) = 48
[pid  9619] getdents(6, /* 0 entries */, 32768) = 0
[pid  9619] close(6)                    = 0
[pid  9619] mount("curlftpfs#ftp://anonymous:anonymous@192.168.3.13/", ".", "fuse", MS_NOSUID|MS_NODEV, "fd=3,rootmode=40000,user_id=1000"...) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
[pid  9619] write(2, "fusermount: mount failed: Operat"..., 50fusermount: mount failed: Operation not permitted
) = 50
[pid  9619] close(3)                    = 0
[pid  9619] exit_group(1)               = ?
[pid  9618] <... recvmsg resumed> {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"", 1}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 0
[pid  9618] close(6)                    = 0
[pid  9618] wait4(9619,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  9619] +++ exited with 1 +++
<... wait4 resumed> NULL, 0, NULL)      = 9619
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=9619, si_uid=1000, si_status=1, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
sendto(4, "QUIT\r\n", 6, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 6
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 1000) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN|POLLRDNORM}])
recvfrom(4, "221 Bye\r\n", 16384, 0, NULL, NULL) = 9
close(4)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with this executable, but my guess is that it needs to run with privilege (probably suid root or similar). strace -f cannot run such a process with privilege unless strace itself is run as root and you may need the -u option.

Comment: Exactly, this does the trick `sudo strace -u marek curlftpfs -o codepage=windows-1250 anonymous:anonymous@192.168.3.13 /home/marek/ftpfs` thank you

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro pardon me but what does this to do with my problem?

Comment: @WakanTanka I read status, never mind.

Comment: @BarefootIO I've now find that there is no SUID bit set on this binary: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 57640 Aug 17  2015 /usr/bin/curlftpfs` isn't this strange?

Comment: @WakanTanka: Again, I've never used these tools, but it seems that curlftpfs uses libfuse which then appears to fork/exec a helper named `fusermount`. This helper is what actually manages the actual mounting and  unmounting. Your trace confirms this. Line 401 execs it without privilege and this is the pid that later fails with EPERM at Line 562.